# IONIC 6 'UploadMappingFileTask' property 'googleServicesResourceRoot' doesn't have a configured value

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic6

When I try to build an android with command **ionic cordova build android --prod --release** build is failing with the error shown below :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease' (type 'UploadMappingFileTask').

  - Type 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.tasks.UploadMappingFileTask' property 'googleServicesResourceRoot' doesn't have a configured value.

    Reason: This property isn't marked as optional and no value has been configured.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Assign a value to 'googleServicesResourceRoot'.
    2. Mark property 'googleServicesResourceRoot' as optional.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#value_not_set for more details about this problem.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 6s

**Ionic Info :**
Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.3 (/home/abhishyam/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.29
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.29
@angular/cli                  : 8.3.29
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 26 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.15.3
native-run (update available: 1.6.0)   : 1.2.2

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/abhishyam/android-sdk)
NodeJS            : v12.19.0 (/home/abhishyam/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/bin/node)
npm               : 6.14.9
OS                : Linux 5.4

**Dependency List:**

````
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.29
+-- @angular-devkit/core@8.3.29
+-- @angular-devkit/schematics@8.3.29
+-- @angular/animations@8.2.14
+-- @angular/cdk@8.2.3
+-- @angular/cli@8.3.29
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@8.2.14
+-- @angular/compiler@8.2.14
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@8.2.14
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@8.2.14
+-- @angular/forms@8.2.14
+-- @angular/http@7.2.16
+-- @angular/language-service@8.2.14
+-- @angular/material@8.2.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@8.2.14
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@8.2.14
+-- @angular/router@8.2.14
+-- @auth0/angular-jwt@3.0.1
+-- @awesome-cordova-plugins/core@5.37.3
+-- @ionic-native/android-permissions@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/app-version@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/barcode-scanner@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/chooser@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/core@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/dialogs@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/file@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/file-path@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/firebase-x@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/geolocation@5.21.5
+-- @ionic-native/google-maps@5.5.0
+-- @ionic-native/http@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/in-app-browser@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/keyboard@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/local-notifications@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/mobile-accessibility@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/native-geocoder@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/network@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/splash-screen@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/status-bar@5.36.0
+-- @ionic-native/unique-device-id@5.36.0
+-- @ionic/angular@4.11.13
+-- @ionic/angular-toolkit@2.3.3
+-- @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy@1.5.8
+-- @ionic/lab@2.0.19
+-- @ionic/storage@2.2.0
+-- @logisticinfotech/ionic4-datepicker@1.4.4
+-- @types/crypto-js@3.1.47
+-- @types/jasmine@3.10.1
+-- @types/jasminewd2@2.0.10
+-- @types/node@14.14.31
+-- @types/xml2js@0.4.5
+-- codelyzer@5.2.2
+-- compare-func@2.0.0
+-- cordova-android@10.1.2
+-- cordova-browser@6.0.0
+-- cordova-multidex@1.0.0 (git+https://github.com/jwall149/cordova-multidex.git#d2358b5845902239f6139c7def0605e5c2dfabed)
+-- cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@2.0.2
+-- cordova-plugin-advanced-http@3.2.2
+-- cordova-plugin-android-permissions@1.1.2
+-- cordova-plugin-androidx@1.0.2
+-- cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter@1.1.3
+-- cordova-plugin-app-version@0.1.12
+-- cordova-plugin-badge@0.8.8
+-- cordova-plugin-chooser@1.3.2
+-- cordova-plugin-device@2.0.3
+-- cordova-plugin-dialogs@2.0.2
+-- cordova-plugin-enable-multidex@0.2.0
+-- cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated@7.8.0
+-- cordova-plugin-file@6.0.2
+-- cordova-plugin-filepath@1.5.6
+-- cordova-plugin-firebasex@13.0.1
+-- cordova-plugin-geolocation@4.0.2
+-- cordova-plugin-googlemaps@2.7.1 (git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps.git#0b8ea76ad34fb2a202a9de1b9d0e051a82ad9443)
+-- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@3.1.0
+-- cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard@2.2.0
+-- cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@4.2.1
+-- cordova-plugin-local-notification@0.9.0-beta.2
+-- cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder@3.4.1
+-- cordova-plugin-network-information@2.0.2
+-- cordova-plugin-proguard@2.2.0
+-- cordova-plugin-splashscreen@5.0.4
+-- cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.4.3
+-- cordova-plugin-unique-device-id2@2.0.0
+-- cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid@1.3.2
+-- cordova-res@0.15.3
+-- cordova-sqlite-storage@6.0.0
+-- cordova-sqlite-storage-dependencies@2.0.0-OS1 (git+https://github.com/OutSystems/cordova-sqlite-storage-dependencies.git#6b3c63e21fa4895d0c22d2a8a12a070befd80f03)
+-- cordova-support-google-services@1.4.1
+-- core-js@3.19.0
+-- crypto-js@3.3.0
+-- hybrid-crypto-js@0.2.4
+-- ionic-calendar-date-picker@0.1.2
+-- ionic4-star-rating@1.1.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jasmine-core@3.4.0
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
+-- jsencrypt@3.0.0-rc.1
+-- karma@4.3.0
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@3.1.0
+-- karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@2.1.1
+-- karma-jasmine@2.0.1
+-- karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
+-- moment@2.29.1
+-- ngx-xml2json@1.0.2
+-- node-rsa@1.1.1
+-- node-sass@4.14.1
+-- nodejs-base64@1.0.3
+-- phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@8.1.0
+-- phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility@1.0.5
+-- protractor@5.4.4
+-- rxjs@6.6.7
+-- stream@0.0.2
+-- timers@0.1.1
+-- ts-node@8.3.0
+-- tslib@1.14.1
+-- tslint@5.19.0
+-- typescript@3.4.5
+-- xcode@3.0.1
+-- xml2js@0.4.22
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.10.3```
````